# iphone progress view

Tags: cocoa-touch

i m trying to make progress view that shows progress according to same speed as receiving data from internet......somebody suggest me....? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Get a look at ASIHttpRequest!
There's plenty of classes that can help you download data from internet, atomically or queued with progress tracking!

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/